# Support collaboration support using facebook on an android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

We have an Android app which allows users to keep track of expenses. We want to take to a next level by supporting collaboration as listed below.

1. Login using facebook.
2. Add other facebook users by (invitation only) as a group.
3. Then all the users in that group use the app to add expenses and then the changes are reflected for everyone.

The objective is that a family can collaboratively work on their expenses.

We want to know how can we start on this. 
Can we leverage the facebook backend instead of creating our own.
What different tools/ technologies will we need to integrate.

Thanks